# Database connection with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, oracle11g

Is it possible to connect Oracle 11g Data Base using only JavaScript and html. If yes then may I know the procedure.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: With javascript you can't to connect to a database. Take a look into node.js..

Comment: Not with only javascript and html. though here is someone doing it by using an activex object : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXXJ-PcEl2Y

Answer (score 0):

No you can not connect to Oracle database with Javascript. Infact you should not try to connect it using client side Javascript as it is considered bad and will have many security issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practise actually. You can connect to sql server like this.

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
 document.write(rs.fields(1));
 rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

Just change the connection string and you are done

Comment: What is `ADODB.Connection`? This is for SQL server connection..right?

Comment: OP has specifically asked about the Oracle connection. This code will not work for Oracle connection. So your answer doesn't help it. Even if does then too you should avoid giving answers which are not recommended or are just a hack.

Comment: Ok Sir , next time will definitely see to it.